# How to remove/clear state stores in Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a custom `Transformer` implementation in the end of my kafka-streams DSL, with a persistent changelog `KeyValueStore` bound to it.

Since few weeks I have been putting way too much data in the store. Now whenever I load the application it eats up way too much RAM.

However, the application itself is just a prototype so I don't mind clearing the store entirely.

I could rename the `kafka.application.id` and the `state-store-name` but that's a temporary workaround(and the corresponding data/topics won't be deleted).

How do I purge it entirely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Confluent's [documentation recommends](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html#step-2-reset-the-local-environments-of-your-application-instances) to either use KafkaStreams.cleanUp(), or manually delete directories at `/var/lib/kafka-streams/<application.id>` (configuration parameter `state.dir`).

You also need to reset all topics used by application with use of [special reset tool](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html) - `bin/kafka-streams-application-reset`:

```
bin/kafka-streams-application-reset --application-id my-streams-app \
                                  --input-topics my-input-topic \
                                  --intermediate-topics rekeyed-topic
```

This [post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/) about resetting the state is very interesting.

Comment: SO question should be self contained. Please copy and cite the corresponding part of the docs (and use links only as reference) -- if content moves, links might become dangling and thus your answer looses it's content. Thx.

Comment: which is exactly what happened the link is navigating to a different place now @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: @curiosityrock the answer should be self-contained after that comment...

Comment: Oh i was referring to KafkaStreams.cleanUp(), the links dont' give any information about that. Is that a function that i can call?

Comment: That’s function that could be called from your Kafka Streams code... but if you don’t want write the code, use other methods mentioned

Comment: The new link is https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html#step-2-reset-the-local-environments-of-your-application-instances