# Clean up application local store when using persistent store in a KafkaStream created with quarkus-kafka-stream plugin

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, quarkus

I created a Kafka Streams, using **quarkus-kafka-stream** extension, that uses a persistent store to keep an aggregate and I would like to kwon how to reset the application properly.
Cause of the persisted aggregated, it's not possible to do a clean re-processing of the input logs using only the Kafka Streams Application Reset Tool.
I already read the [Confluent documentation](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/) and some other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681844/how-to-remove-clear-state-stores-in-kafka-streams) where people suggest to call `KafkaStreams.cleanUp()` method or delete the folder `/var/lib/kafka-streams/<application.id>`, but I think that the situation is a little more tricky with Quarkus.

In my application I wrote the method that produces the topology while the application lifecycle is managed by the plugin so I don't have the reference of the `KafkaStreams` object on which call the `cleanUp()` method. Surely I can re-create that object but I'm not sure this is the right way.

Am I missing something?
Can someone please clarify to me how it's supposed to be done?
If you need further information just ask me.

Thank you
Have a nice day
_
Mauro